# Smart Group DB error

Tags: error, smartgroups

Viewing some Smart groups (not all) causes DB error.

```
[error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
[callback] => Array
    (
        [0] => CRM_Core_Error
        [1] => exceptionHandler
    )

[code] => -2
[message] => DB Error: syntax error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_554616ac5a2e5773984de236f4af031e (group_id, contact_id)  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_554616ac5a2e5773984de236f4af031e (group_id, contact_id)  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_554616ac5a2e5773984de236f4af031e (group_id, contact_id)  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]"]
)
```

I think, this error is since the last, 5.26.1 update.

Has someone this problem, too?

Comment: Recently upgraded from 5.20.3 to 5.26.1 and having similar issue. With the addition that the affected smart groups are used for user ACL management.

Comment: As it is a possible regression I notified the Product Maintenance channel https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/xim58dupridbuqxypdysda3eyr.

Comment: Does these groups have any parents or children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been reported here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17622 and it should be fixed by the [CiviCRM 5.26.2](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.26/release-notes/5.26.2.md).

Comment: We just started experiencing this error in 5.29.0, is anyone who previously had this issue experiencing a regression, or is there possibly a new error now? (we went from 5.25 to 5.27 so never experienced this previously)