# Mailings - DB Error: syntax error

Tags: drupal, mailing

I'm testing out Civicrm. Started with Wordpress then copied the database into Drupal 7

When trying to send a mailing to a group, the send test email issues

**Error in call to Mailing_send_test : DB Error: syntax error**

And trying to submit the mailing gives
**DB Error: syntax error**

From the logs I can see

```
 [code] => -2
[message] => DB Error: syntax error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_e014dbed46046aa1c0657ac431a08f53 (group_id, contact_id)  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_e014dbed46046aa1c0657ac431a08f53 (group_id, contact_id)  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_e014dbed46046aa1c0657ac431a08f53 (group_id, contact_id)  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]"]
```

Edit - looks like this is the same issue as [Smart Group DB error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35868/smart-group-db-error)

Answer given was - It has been reported here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17622 and it should be fixed by the CiviCRM 5.26.2.

Answer (score 2):

Tested the fix from https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17622 & can confirm it's now working as expected.

Comment: We just started experiencing this error in 5.29.0, is anyone who previously had this issue experiencing a regression, or is there possibly a new error now? (we went from 5.25 to 5.27 so never experienced this previously)

Answer (score 0):

We just experienced this with the newest version October 2022 /54.
In relation to smart groups and the search function. Also when exporting contacts. Is the patch from 2020 safe?

'***ERROR***
message:            DB Error: syntax error
code:
exception:          PEAR_Exception Object
(
[cause:protected] => DB_Error Object
(
[error_message_prefix] =>
[mode] => 16
[level] => 1024
[code] => -2
[message] => DB Error: syntax error
[userinfo] => INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_1e5c7912afe5baa5f381309ac26f4b75 (group_id, contact_id) SELECT 486 AS group_id, contact_a.id as id  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a     WHERE  (  ( contact_a.created_date >= '20191001000000' )  )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.id NOT IN (
SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact
WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed'
AND civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 486 )   [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';= '20191001000000' ) )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND contact_a.id NOT IN' at line 1]
[backtrace] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[file] => /srv/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php
[line] => 997
[function] => __construct
[class] => PEAR_Error
[type] => ->
[args] => Array
(
[0] => DB Error: syntax error
[1] => -2
[2] => 16
[3] => Array
(
[0] => CRM_Core_Error
[1] => exceptionHandler
)

```
                               [4] => INSERT IGNORE INT...
```

***LAST ERROR***
Array
(
[type] => 16384
[message] => Calling the "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface::dispatch()" method with the event name as the first argument is deprecated since Symfony 4.3, pass it as the second argument and provide the event object as the first argument instead.
[file] => /srv/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php
[line] => 58
)
'

Comment: My solution was - - - Mysql settings: more power 1GB